# shorthand notation for query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a method to give a shorthand notation to a query?

ex.

```
Q1 = (select * from tablename2) 

Q2 = (select * from tablename2)

select name from Q1; 
select name from Q2;
```

I am aware of views but I do not intend to use them.

Comment: Views seem to do exactly what you want, why don't you want to use them?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [Create a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).

```
CREATE VIEW Q1 AS (
  SELECT 
    name,
    id,
    othercol
  FROM tablename1
);

/* Works with a WHERE clause too */
CREATE VIEW Q2 AS (
  SELECT 
    name,
    id,
    othercol
  FROM tablename2
  WHERE othercol = 'some limitation'
);

SELECT name FROM Q1;
/* aggregates work too */
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM Q2 GROUP BY name;
```

Note: It is not recommended to `SELECT *` in a view (or really anywhere in production code). Always be explicit about the columns in the select list so their order will be deterministic.

Alternatively, create a temporary table using the [`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html).

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Q1 
  SELECT name, id, othercol FROM tablename1;

/* select from it */
SELECT name FROM Q1 WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)

/* When done, drop it. Otherwise, it will be dropped when the client connection terminates. */
DROP TABLE Q1;
```

Comment: thanks michael but I am aware of views, is there anything else apart from views ?

Comment: @AK Alternatively, you could use a temporary table.

Comment: Views are exactly what you're talking about, though.

Comment: You can absolutely use an IN clause in a VIEW (and subselects). MySQL is not *that* limited.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I had a FAIL with my example and intended to show a view with an IN subquery rather than straight up IN clause.  But a test on 5.5.2 reveals to me that you are right and you actually _can_ use an IN() subquery in a view now. That was not possible in earlier versions (maybe was _much_ earlier though, like 5.0).  Still can't use a subquery in the FROM clause though...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Wow, another one of those stupid limits. I didn't know that. MySQL really did mess up their SQL parser. Btw: to be precise: a sub-query (`where id in (select ..)`is allowed a derived table (`from (select ... from ) t`)  is not

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about views. check out the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) for them.

Answer (score 0):

A view is similar to what you're looking for.

But a "view" is less a notational convenience than an "alias" or "facade" for other queries or updates. A good metaphore is "a view is a virtual table". In MSSQL, "views" can also be an effective way to enhance security.

Here is a good article on the subject:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068%28v=sql.80%29.aspx